# Custom ActionFilterAttribute in .Net Core 3.1 returning: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.1, actionfilterattribute, custom-action-filter

I am migrating my .Net Core 2.2 app to version 3.1.

I have the following Action Filter:

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly int _num;
    private readonly string _type;

    public MyFilterAttribute(string name, int num, string type)
    {
        _name = name;
        _num = num;
        _type = type;
    }

    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        ...
        await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
    }
}
```

I register this filter in the Startup.cs file like this:

```
services.AddTransient<MyFilterAttribute>();
```

And I use the filter inside my Controllers like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [MyFilter("some-name", 5000, "some-type")]
    public async Task MyAction()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This filter worked perfectly in my .Net Core 2.2 app. However now when I'm trying to migrate to version 3.1 I get the following exception:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.AggregateException An unhandled
>   exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll: 'Some services are not
>   able to be constructed'  Inner exceptions found, see $exception in
>   variables window for more details.  Innermost exception
>   System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to resolve service for type
>   'System.String' while attempting to activate
>   'my_app.Filters.MyFilterAttribute'.    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type
>   serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain,
>   ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache
>   lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain
>   callSiteChain)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor
>   descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(ServiceDescriptor
>   serviceDescriptor, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.ValidateService(ServiceDescriptor
>   descriptor)

I tried to add the filter globally like this:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add<MyFilterAttribute>();
})
```

But I'm having the same error.

Did something change in the way .Net Core reads custom filters in .Net Core 3.1?

I'm not seeing anything relevant in the migration breaking changes documentation.

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that worked when added to the service collection in the previous version. `public MyFilterAttribute(string name, int num, string type)` The container wont know how to resolve those parameters

Comment: @Nkosi i understand what you're saying, and yet i have a working .net core 2.2 app in production with this exact filter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex and Nkosi answers (/comments) are correct, the problem with the first implementation was that the filter was constructed in the Dependency Injection mechanism and the DI didn't know how to deal with the string arguments.

I honestly don't know how this worked, but I do have a .Net Core 2.2 app live in production with filters implemented this way.

Anyway, I changed the filter to be a `TypeFilterAttribute` and now it works again in .Net Core 3.1 (no need to register it in the DI):

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public MyFilterAttribute(params object[] arguments) : base(typeof(MyFilterAttributeImpl))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { arguments };
    }

    private class MyFilterAttributeImpl : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly string _name;
        private readonly int _num;
        private readonly string _type;

        public MyFilterAttribute(object[] arguments)
        {
            _name = (string)arguments[0];
            _num = (int)arguments[1];
            _type = (string)arguments[2];
        }

        public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            ...
            await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
        }
    }
}
```

With this implementation where we first define a `TypeFilterAttribute` and call an `ActionFilterAttribute` inside it, we can call the filter with a nice looking annotation:

`[MyFilter("some-name", 5000, "some-type")]`

instead of:

`[TypeFilter(typeof(MyFilterAttribute), Arguments = new object[] { "some-name", 5000, "some-type" })]`

Answer (score 1):

According to this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1), all your action filters are resolved by DI which means your 2 string params will be resolved as well. And that caused you the error.

You may want to consider use different type of filter that doesn't need to be resolved by DI.

Have a look at 2 types of filter at

```
public class AddHeaderAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
```

Comment: Specifically this section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#dependency-injection

Comment: You should quote the specific parts into this answer otherwise this is more suited as a comment.